# Approach to Data Transfer Methods from Operational data store to Dimensional data source

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, etl, data-warehouse

I use `SQL Server 2008` and I work with `SSAS`.

I need to fill my `Data Warehouse` from my `Operational data store(ODS)`.

I create my `Facts` and 'Dimensions' in my 'Data Warehouse' and I have some `Tables` in my `ODS` what is the best way for transfer data from `ODS` to `DDS` with consider that maybe one deleted record in `ODS` cause one update or one delete inside `DDS`.

My strategy like this :

```
 OLTP Database -> Stage Database -> ODS Database -> DDS
```

Each day my OLTP change come to `Stage Database` with `SSIS Package` and with another `SSIS Package` this changes (Insert/Update/Delete) in `Stage Database` transfer to `ODS Database` then `Stage Database` will be truncate.

Now how I can transfer my change (Insert/Update/Delete) inside `ODS` to `DDS`.

For more description I most tell that for fill my tables inside `ODS` I most run some view that have `Group By` and some things like this.

in the other hand, how i can change my data in `DDS` consider change that happened in `ODS` ?

Can `Chapter Data Change` in `Tables of ODS` help me?

What is the best approach to Data Transfer from `Operational data store` to `Dimensional data source`?